# WCF doesn't update proxy

Tags: c#, wcf

I have problem with updating proxy from wcf service.I have interface with one operationcontract and one datacontract,everything was working until I've added one new operationcontract...When I try to update service from client app generated proxy is without new operationcontracts.I've tried use svcutil but without success,the same result. 
Any idea what's wrong?

```
[ServiceContract] 
public interface ICreationService 
{ 
    [OperationContract] bool CreateTicket(Ticket ticket); 
    [OperationContract] bool CreateTicket(Ticket ticket,bool asd);
    [OperationContract] IEnumerable<Ticket> GetTickets(); 
} 

[DataContract] 
public class Ticket 
{ 
    [DataMember] 
    public string Name { get; set; } 

    [DataMember] 
    public int Severity { get; set; } 

    [DataMember] 
    public string Description { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Can you post the new contract you added and also your bindings?

Comment: [ServiceContract]
 public interface ICreationService
 {
  [OperationContract]
        bool CreateTicket(Ticket ticket);

        [OperationContract]
        bool CreateTicket(Ticket ticket,bool asd);
        //
        [OperationContract]
        IEnumerable<Ticket> GetTickets();
 }

    [DataContract]
    public class Ticket
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int Severity { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

Comment: in order for people to help you, you'll have to show us your web.config, the updated contract, and the exception that you see when you browse to the service in a web browser

Answer (score 1):

WCF does not allow you to have more than one method with the same name (no overloading). You need to change the name of one of your `CreateTicket` methods, **or** you can add name attributes to your method like so:

```
 [OperationContract(Name="CreateTicketNewName")]
 bool CreateTicket(Ticket ticket);
```

EDIT

Try returning a concrete type instead of an interface.  There's a similar thread on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853554/problem-with-using-ienumerable-types-as-return-types-in-wcf)

Comment: thanks, for tip but even when I deleted it, method IEnumerable<Ticket> GetTickets() is not reflected in proxy ...

Comment: this inteface is generated in proxy:    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="ServiceReference2.ICreationService")]
    public interface ICreationService {
        
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/ICreationService/CreateTicket", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/ICreationService/CreateTicketResponse")]
        bool CreateTicket(Web.ServiceReference2.Ticket ticket);
    } ... still there isn't method GetTickets() ... any idea?I'm lost

Comment: @user1275513, modify your GetTickets() to return a concrete class instead of IEnumerable

Comment: I've tried to change it to List<> but still it was not working ...so I decided to create new service but now I'm not able to get endpoint when my host is running ... something is probably global wrong in my project