# How to use [DataMember] for IEnumerable<string> for property in WCF

Tags: wcf

I am trying to use [DataContract] and [DataMember] for the below class.

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class TestClass
{
    #region Public Contructors        
    protected TestClass()
    {
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Properties   

    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<string> Subjects { get; set; }

    #endregion      


}
```

**I get the following error**

> Cannot serialize member TestClass.Subjects
>   of type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.String,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] because it is an interface

What should I to fix this issue please?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853554/problem-with-using-ienumerable-types-as-return-types-in-wcf

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, you can't serialize an Interface like `IEnumerable`.
Try using a concrete collection like `List<string>` or even `string[]`.

Keep in mind that the `serialized` classes that you send over WCF will probably better to be surrogate classes or DTO, so this way you don't mess up your Business Model.

Hope this helps